# Angular-CLI incorrectly detects need for upgrade from beta 10

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 project, generated using angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.18. It has been working fine.

Today I upgraded to angluar-cli 1.0.0-beta-19-3, both globally and in my project.

Now when I try to run ng commands it gives this advice

```
> ng serve

It seems like you're using a project generated using an old version of the Angular CLI.
The latest CLI now uses webpack and includes a lot of improvements, include a simpler
workflow, a faster build and smaller bundles.

To get more info, including a step-by-step guide to upgrade the CLI, follow this link:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14
```

However, I am not upgrading from beta 10. The referenced web page concerns migrating from SystemJS to webpack, but I am already on webpack (since 1.0.0-beta.18 generated a webpack based project)

How can I get my project running again?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by completely erasing `node_modules` and doing `npm install`.

[The instructions actually says that](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) you need to erase `node_modules`. I have never had to do that, but apparently they are correct.